# product images are broken magento ver. 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have moved Magento website form demo to live server ! now looks like product page images are broken , in all pages some static image is coming , category listing pages images are working fine !

[image: product page image]

my website link is [product page link is](https://www.rialitradecentre.com.au/aus-crete-mpa.html)

I didn't find any solution in online! any one please let me know where I am wrong !

Comment: did you try clearing the product images cache? https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/cache-management.html#flush-the-product-image-cache

Comment: try resizing catalog images. `catalog:images:resize` command

Comment: yes , i tried to clear the image cache and i tried to resize the image ! still facing same issue